# Create a `Core` class containing common methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using a lot of methods repeatedly in various screens. I tried creating a core class that contain these methods and then call them in the various controllers as needs. One was to return the navigation bar when it was hidden, I am not entirely sure how to do it. This is what I tried:

```
Core.h


-(void) returnNavBar;
```

and

```
Core.m

-(void) returnNavBar{
     //show navigation bar - hidden in TabBarController
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

}
```

However `self.navigationController` is highlighted in yellow. Please ask questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of your navigationController property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have declared the method in core.c, the methods will be associated with the core class, so `self.navigationController` won't be defined - your core class doesn't have this property.  Even if you did define this property it wouldn't be initialised to the navigationController of the calling class.

One way you can do this is to use class methods and pass in all of the required parameters, so you would have

```
Core.h

+(void) returnNavBar:(UINavigationController *)navController;

Core.m

+ (void) returnNavBar:(UINavigationController *)navController
{
    [navController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Note the "+" rather than "-" which flags this as a class method

To invoke it you would call

```
    [core returnNavBar:self.NavigationController];
```

but it is debatable as to whether this is actually any quicker or clearer than simply putting the setNavigationBarHidden call there.  It might make more sense for more complex operations.

Comment: It works thank you. It is indeed debatable whether this is quicker. Im trying to get used to best practices at the moment, whether I use it for the above methods is another thing but the explanation is very and will be very helpful in the future

Answer (score 3):

The use of `self` is wrong in this case, since `self` in this case is the the instance of a `Core` object which is not an `UIViewController` and therefore does not have a property `navigationController`.

What you want in a Objective-C Category on `UIViewController`.

UIViewController+Core.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIViewController (Core)

-(void) returnNavBar;

@end
```

UIViewController+Core.m

```
#import "UIViewController+Core.h"

@implementation UIViewController (Core)

-(void) returnNavBar{
     //show navigation bar - hidden in TabBarController
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];    
}

@end
```

Then just import the `UIViewController+Core.h` in yout viewcontroller .m file and you can call the `returnNavBar` method.